# How to create second column by adding the values in first column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Below given table ABC has column Num and second column should be created by adding the values in column first. 
Table ABC

```
Num
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output

```
Num  Num2
1    1
2    3
3    6
4    9
5    12
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Please tag the question appropriately.  Also, the last number is not calculated correctly.

Comment: The last **two** numbers are not calculated correctly. (Unless the OP meant something different altogether...)

Comment: Yes its working correctly for first 3 records.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports the ANSI standard method of calculating cumulative sums:

```
select num, sum(num) over (order by num)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can do this in MYSQL

```
SELECT    T.* ,
             @SUM:=@SUM + T.num AS RunningTotal
FROM     (SELECT @SUM:=0) S,T
```